# using header files in php extension build

Tags: php, c, php-extension

I need to include header files in php extension that I'm building. I have tried everything I know but is not working.

I have header files for one module in a different directory

```
D:\\viba
```

which contains header files and .lib file. I'm trying to include a header file 'viba.h' in one of my extension files but I get the following error:

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'viba.h': No such file or directory
```

In my config.w32 file I have already included:

```
CHECK_HEADER_ADD_INCLUDE("viba.h", "CFLAGS_VIBA", "D:\\viba")
```

During build this check succeeds but the inclusion of "viba.h" in extension files do not work. I may be missing something since the inclusion of php files work although they are also located in different directories up.

There are no problems with the following includes:

```
#include "php.h"
#include "php_ini.h"
#include "zend_exceptions.h"
#include "ext/standard/info.h"
```

Since these includes are also located in different directories but still work, I might be missing something which generates this error for the includes of "viba.h"

```
#include "viba.h"  // this include generates error
```

I'm stuck, please help.

Comment: Daniel, can you please share your makefile? It would help us to support you.

Comment: Ok, sorry, found Makefile in the php source directory. It's 880 lines long and I don't how to make it available to you. Pasting will be long.

Comment: Thanks, problem solved now. The problem was in the the value I provided to 'CHECK_HEADER_ADD_INCLUDE' for the flags (the second parameter). Now the extension compiles and links without any problem.